# Facebook Android authorization dialog immediately disappears

Tags: android, facebook

I'm testing what happens if the user hasn't granted all the necessary permissions.  My in-progress app was working fine. Then I went into my privacy settings on Facebook and deleted some of the permissions for my app.

Back in my app, after logging out and back in, I need to request those permissions again:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, READ_PERMISSIONS));
```

When I do so, I see a loading spinner, then a dialog box titled Facebook with a loading spinner in it and a cancel button, and then that dialog box immediately closes. OnSessionStateChanged gets called with a state of OPENED, not OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED as desired, but also not unexpected, since the user was never given a chance to approve the permission.

If I log out and try to log back in along with my Publish permissions, I get the dialog asking me to approve the publish permission, but after clicking OK, it does not log me in.

If I go to the Graph API Explorer and request a token with those permissions, thereby granting them, then I can log into my app again on the phone.

Comment: go to you facebook privacy settings and remove the app completely. I suspect you already have that permission, that's why the dialogue closes immediately and also the token doesn't get updated.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't help. That resulted in me being unable to log in as well. I could only log in again after granting my app access through Graph API Explorer. But the permissions are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had inadvertantly introduced a typo in one of my permissions (friends_status -> friend_status) and kept missing the log warnings from com.facebook.katana because I was testing on a Nexus device, so the console is spammed constantly with the nativegetenabledtags message. My filter to hide the spam also hid the Facebook warning message.